# My input: onChange handler is not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

I'm creating a React.js PWA.
I have an input field with an onChange property in it.

`<input onChange={(e) => handleInput(e)} />`

In my desktop browsers this works perfectly fine, but in my mobile browser it seems that the onChange handler wont be fired.
I also tried to directly `alert()` the onChange.

`<input onChange={() => alert()} />`

Again in the desktop browser it works perfectly fine, but in my mobile browser it doesn't.

---

**Additional Information:**

- I use Styled Components to create my input element
- I use React Hooks to update the state values
- Phone: iPhone Xr - iOS 12.3.1
- Browsers tested: Safari(web-view and PWA-view) and Google Chrome

---

**Also tried:**

- Use simple `input` element(So without Styled Components)
- Changed type to `text` or `number`
- Changed key to something what is 100% unique

---

**My code**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';


const StyledInput = styled.input`

`;

const Input = (props) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        setValue(props.value));
    }, []);

    return (
        <StyledInput
            key="key_value"
            type="tel"
            value={value}
            onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: Need more information. On what mobile browser is it not working?

Comment: @Karan all of the mobile browsers. I'll update my Additional information...

Comment: Can you please try these: 1. change type to text instead of tel. 2. Use simple input and not styled input. This will tell us if its the styled component issue or something with react.

Comment: But ofcourse it should not matter in wich Browser I am. It should work in each browser...

Comment: @Karan also tried those actions ;)

Comment: So, none of the steps worked?
Also, I noticed you used alert. Did you check if you disabled alert popups in your browser? Maybe the function got triggered but the alerts are disabled.

Comment: @Karan when I did an `onClick={() => alert()}` it gives me the alert box

Comment: @Karan indeed, none of the steps worked

Comment: WIth your useEffect hook you are calling setValue(props) every time the component updates, while the value of props doesn't update. I assume you want to create a default state? This can be done by using `useState(props.value)` and remoing the useEffect part.

Comment: @IdsvanderZee I understand what you are saying here. I have my reasons why I use the useEffect and the update on `props.value`. But this is not the solution. It is definite the `onChange` property

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/GodLik3/haqv5ynj/
I tried replicating your problem. But seems to be working on mobile as well. Please have a look once. If the fiddle perfectly replicates your code.

Comment: Yes, this does work perfectly. So then it should be somewhere else in code :s

Comment: Exactly. Please check.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out where the problem was.

I had an `css-reset.css` which resets the css in every browser.

I had:

```
 * { 
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -khtml-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
}
```

DON'T DO THIS! xD