# React - events do not work on mobile keyboard (onChange, onKeyDown...)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, onchange, keyboard-events

I am working on an autocomplete function for a website and using React. This works fine for Web browsers so far. It works through the `onChange` function of the `<input>` html element, like this.

```html
<input
  title="Enter Search Term"
  placeholder="Enter term..."
  className="h-8 w-full p-1 text-black text-m"
  // value={textboxValue}
  onChange={inputChangeUpdate}
  // onChange={(e) => handleTextBoxUpdate(e.currentTarget.value)}
/>
```

I have a commented two commented out properties - the `onChange` worked fine previously but would simply not trigger at all for mobile devices, so I switched it to the other `onChange` event, but I cannot extract the value at all from it. Commenting out `value` seems to have had no effect.

From what I have researched, React does not support the onChange event for mobile devices or virtual keyboards. I am really stuck here as this seems like a reasonably basic function to perform, but have tried using refs and quite a few different combinations of trying to access the value directly.

Is this possible at all? Any help would be much appreciated, I have spent hours trying to find an answer to this online!

These are the receiving methods:

```js
const handleTextBoxUpdate = (value: string, clearSuggested?: boolean) => {
  toggleInvalidTermText(false);
  let newValue = value;
  setTextboxValue(newValue);
  if (newValue.length > 2 && !clearSuggested) {
    populateSuggestedSearch(newValue);
  } else {
    setSuggestedTerms([]);
  }
};

const inputChangeUpdate = (e: React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  // @ts-ignore
  const input = e.currentTarget.value;
  handleTextBoxUpdate(input);
  console.log(input)
}
```

I've tried using refs to get the value, passing the event and getting the value, different ways of catching the `onChange` event, other events to monitor change in the input and none of them work, and the value is just simply not being caught. What I expected to happen is that on mobile keyboards it would trigger the change in value, since it is held on the screen somehow.

Comment: Seems related https://stackoverflow.com/a/57076093/7679903

Comment: What `console.log(input)` prints on mobile?

Comment: Hi @BadalSaibo unfortunately that was one of the questions I found too but was not related to my issue

Comment: @Konrad I managed to check the console and it turns out it's a CORS error instead, it appears to only be an issue on iPhone browsers so far, I haven't tested it on Android

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this did in fact work, and what was causing the issue was a CORS error. I tested this on Safari and Google Chrome (iOS 15 or 16 I believe), and it was because the URL I was using was attempted to access HTTP rather than HTTPS!

[This comment fixed it for me!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72763673/20813390)